# Pandas stacked bar plot with multi week data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` as follows:

```
Week     Instrument   Trader Count
1        Stock         100
1        Bond          50
1        MBS           20
2        Stock         150
2        Bond          500
2        MBS           200
```

I want to created a stacked bar plot such that `week` is the `x-axis` and `Trader Count` is on the `y-axis` as a stacked bar and the `Instrument` is color coded.

I tried `df.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(20,10), x='Week')` but it resulted in unstacked bars. Also my full dataset has 52 weeks of data, so its quite large to plot, and I want to set the week labels ticked few weeks apart.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like pivot is good solution for your problem. Here is the code.

```
df.pivot(index='Week', columns='Instrument', values='Trader Count').plot.bar()
```

This results into bar plots like these.
[bar-plot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnMFO.png)
[bar-plot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewSlc.png)